# Firefox extension automatically Update (silently without popup and any notification)

Tags: firefox-addon, auto-update

I followed the instructions on http://www.borngeek.com/firefox/automatic-firefox-extension-updates/ for setting up extension updates. I uploaded `update.rdf` and extension XPI file to a local server (App Engine server). I started the browser and after some time the Add-on Manager shows available updates. But they are not installed automatically (clicking the "Update" button is still necessary).

What do I need to do to have updates install automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most extensions require Firefox to be restarted after an update. So the Add-on Manager will detect and download updates but it will not interrupt the user. The updates will install automatically when Firefox is started next time.

Only exception are [bootstrapped extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions/Bootstrapped_extensions) that don't require a restart (this includes all add-ons created with the [Add-on SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/developers/builder)). These extensions can be updated while Firefox is running. However, they also have a whole lot of limitations.

Comment: yes, thats true in my case it shows the update now, when we clicked the update now then start the downloading.I need automatically download the updated version, so what should i do.....

Comment: I started browser after some time in the addon manager it shows the 'update now'(available update addons), but when i click the 'update now' button thed start the downloading updated version then we need to restart the browser. I dont want to click the update now button. How should i download the updated version please help me.. thank u

Comment: That's the theory, but in practice, I'm finding that on both my computers, I need to manually force addon updates, at which point half the addons suddenly find there are updates available. Despite the "automatically check..." being ticked.

Comment: @romkyns: That "theory" works for most people given that 80% of my users install an update within 3 days. Note that automatic updates can be disabled both globally and for individual add-ons - double-click the add-on entry in Add-ons Manager to see its update setting. Maybe that's the issue in your case. If not - asking on http://superuser.com/ might help.